# simple insert procedure, check for duplicate

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I am creating a program that is going to insert data into a table which is pretty simple

But my issue is I want my insert statement to make sure that it isnt inserting duplicate data

I want to somehow check the table the data is going into to make sure that there isnt a row with the same indivualid and categoryid and value

So if I am inserting

```
indivualid = 1
categorid = 1
value = 1
```

and in my table there is a row with

```
indivualid = 1
categorid = 1
value = 2
```

my data would still be inserted

but if there was a row with

```
indivualid = 1
categorid = 1
value = 1
```

then it wouldnt

I tried this

```
IF @value = 'Y'
OR @value = 'A'
OR @value = 'P'
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT categoryid,
          individualid
   FROM ualhistory
   WHERE categoryid = @cat
     AND individualid = @id)
INSERT INTO individuory(categoryid, individualid, value, ts)
VALUES (@cat,
        @id,
        @yesorno,
        getdate())
```

but it still inserts duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in the following manner:

```
insert into 
individuory(categoryid, individualid, value, ts) 
VALUES (@cat, @id, @yesorno, getdate()) 
where not exists 
(select 1 from individuory where categoryid=@cat and individualid=@id)
```

Now, the exact problem with your approach is that you are not associating the ORs and therefore, the condition becomes true and always inserts the data. You can change your statement to this:

```
if ((@value = 'Y' or @value = 'A' or @value = 'P') 
and not EXISTS 
(SELECT categoryid, individualid FROM ualhistory WHERE categoryid = @cat 
 and individualid = @id) )
 INSERT INTO individuory(categoryid, individualid, value, ts) 
 VALUES (@cat, @id, @yesorno, getdate())
```

And I think it will work also.

Comment: i tryed the second method as it is how i was trying to do it, but it still inserts duplicate records

Comment: ahh i got it i didnt have the if in ()

Comment: @bugz No, that's impossible. The way you are doing it was almost correct except for the fact that you were missing a couple of ( and ). Give a try to my last statement.

Comment: @bugz glad it worked. Yeah, I noticed that you were missing the ().

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE individuory
ADD CONSTRAINT myConstarint
UNIQUE (categoryid, individualid, value)
```

Comment: if i add this constraint does it mean only values with all 3 must be equal in a row or does it reject all rows with a categoryid thats the same but indidualid and value are different

Comment: @bugz, why not try it and see?  but the answer is that it is a unique constraint on the combination of all three columns.

Comment: for example, if there is already record `indivualid = 1, categorid = 2,
value = 3` another record with `indivualid = 1, categorid = 2,
value = 3` will not be inserted

Comment: Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'myConstraint' has maximum length of 8008 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.
Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX terminated because a duplicate key was found for index ID 6. Most significant primary key is '2'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on (individualid, categoryid, value) and the server won't let you insert a duplicate row.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189862.aspx